# loading pretrained (CNN) model from .ckpt file using Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I am using Pytorch for image classification. I am looking for CNN models pretrained on a dataset other than ImageNet, I have found a link to a ".ckpt" file. I also found tutorials on loading this file with Tenserflow, but not using pytorch. 
How can I load pretrained model using Pytorch from ".ckpt" file ?

Comment: tensorflow and pytorch aren't interoperable. If the checkpoint is for a tensorflow model then it won't be trivial to use with pytorch.

Comment: Is that file a torch file or a tensorflow file? Could it be possible that the file could be loaded using pytorch-lightning? Try model.load_from_checkpoint(path_to_ckpt_file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @jodag that in general, PyTorch and Tensorflow are not interoperable. There are some special cases in which you may be able to do this. For example, HuggingFace provides support for converting the [transformer model from TensorFlow to PyTorch](https://huggingface.co/transformers/converting_tensorflow_models.html).

There is a [related (though closed) question on DataScience StackExchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40496/how-to-convert-my-tensorflow-model-to-pytorch-model) where the idea is to rewrite the Tensorflow model into PyTorch and then loads the weights from the checkpoint file. Note that this can get tricky at times.